# Limiting what jsoup retrieves

Tags: java, android, listview, jsoup

I'm Having fun learning to use jsoup and have successfully retrieved and displayed data from a website, but now I would like some further guidance on it if anyone can help.

Using the code below returns all the table rows 30+, How can I retrieve only say the first 10 of those rows?

also

When returning those rows and the data on them there are gaps/spaces in the row between the data, the spaces between rows are fine but its the spaces within the row that I want to get rid of, how can I omit those spaces/gaps?

My code so far...

```
package com.example.shiftzer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

TextView textView1;
ListView shippingList; 

  public static final String APP_PREFERENCES = "AppPrefs";
    SharedPreferences settings; 
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor;

   @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {         
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        //rest of the code

       textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
       shippingList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

       settings = getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
       prefEditor = settings.edit();

       new VTSTask().execute();//starts AsyncTask in private class VTSTask to get      shipping info
    }

   private class VTSTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<String>> {
       ArrayList<String> arr_shipping=new ArrayList<String>();
        /**
         * @param args
         */
        @Override
        protected ArrayList<String>  doInBackground(Void... params) {

            Document doc;
            String shippingList;

            try {
                doc =   Jsoup.connect("https://vts.mhpa.co.uk/main_movelistb.asp").get(); 
                Elements tableRows = doc.select("table.dynlist tr   td");

                 for (Element element : tableRows) {
                      shippingList = element.text();
                      arr_shipping.add(shippingList);// add value to  ArrayList
                    } 
                 } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }      

            return arr_shipping;//<< Return ArrayList from here
        }

         @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {        
             //TextView tVShipping= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

             shippingList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
             ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = 
                 new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, 
                                           android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
                                          android.R.id.text1);

             for (String shipping_result : result)
             {
                adapter.add(shipping_result);
             }

             // Assign adapter to ListView
             shippingList.setAdapter(adapter); 

          }
    }


}
```

Thank you.

EDIT:

```
try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect("https://vts.mhpa.co.uk/main_movelistb.asp").get(); 
                Elements tableRows = doc.select("table.dynlist tr td");

                tableRows.size();
                        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                                  tableRows.get(i);
                   shippingList  = tableRows.get(i).text() +"\n";

                      arr_shipping.add(shippingList);// add value to ArrayList
                    } 
                 } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }      

            return arr_shipping;//<< return ArrayList from here
        }
```

Comment: what do you mean by spaces/gaps ? &nbsp;?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This**

```
   import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
    import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
    import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

    public class test
    {

         static ArrayList<String> arr_shipping=new ArrayList<String>();
     public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
      {
         try {
            Document  doc = Jsoup.connect("https://vts.mhpa.co.uk/main_movelistb.asp").timeout(600000).get(); 
             Elements tableRows = doc.select("table.dynlist tr:not(:eq(0))");

             tableRows.size();
                     for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                               //tableRows.get(i);
              String  shippingList =tableRows.get(i).text() +"\n";

                   arr_shipping.add(shippingList);// add value to ArrayList
                   System.out.println(shippingList);
                 } 
              } catch (IOException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
         }      

       //  return arr_shipping;//<< return ArrayList from here

      }

    }
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer and I have accepted it, going further can you explain what is happening here: doc.select("table.dynlist tr:not(:eq(0))"); ? thanks.

Comment: am selecting the table class that equals "dynlist" so it give me the table you wanted then  "tr:not(:eq(0)" shows all the rows except the first row, which is like the header/tile and stuff am sure u don't need. Am glad it helped you, thanks for marking it as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of doing for(Element element:tableRows), Elements has a size method.

So, you should be able to just do some validation with the size, and then simply

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  tableRows.get(i);
}
```

to get 10 of them.

As for the spaces, before you store them in your arraylist just use regular expressions and remove the spaces.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Comment: Alexander Lin. Hi, I am trying your suggestion and have edited my question with what I have so far but it is still returning the whole list could you point out any errors please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
doc.select("table.dynlist tr:lt(10)");
```

to limt the results.

[**Reference**](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)