# How can I specify amount of hyperlinks returned by jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

I am working on a project, where I need to write a Java code to return hyperlinks from the web-page.

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;  
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;  
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;  
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;  
public class link_demo {  
     public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException{  
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.javatpoint.com").get();  
            Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");  
            for (Element link : links) {  

                    System.out.println("\nlink : " + link.attr("href"));  
                    System.out.println("text : " + link.text());  
            }       
     }  
}
```

This is the code that returns hyperlinks, but when I ran it, it returns all the links. I only need first 10 to be returned. Is there a way I can achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just using the first 10 of the returned List? So restricting the loop to the first 10 would do the trick, no?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limiting what jsoup retrieves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18390982/limiting-what-jsoup-retrieves)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Elements` implements `Collection`. So you can process it as a stream.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.javatpoint.com").get();  
Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");  
links.stream()
    .limit(10)
    .forEach(link -> {  
        System.out.println("\nlink : " + link.attr("href"));  
        System.out.println("text : " + link.text());  
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not using an index to store the count,and only get the first 10 records

```
public class link_demo {  
     public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException{  
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.javatpoint.com").get();  
            Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
            int index = 0;          
            for (Element link : links) {  
                if(index >= 10){
                  break;
                }
                index++;
                System.out.println("\nlink : " + link.attr("href"));  
                System.out.println("text : " + link.text());  
            }       
     }  
}
```